# PopUp control IsOpen property always returning false

Tags: wpf, popup, contextmenu

I have a simple popup control which i want to use in my wpf application for contextmenu but its isOpen property is always showing false and my poup is not showing. I tried changing it in xaml as well as through my code but all in vain. Can anybody tell me why this unexpected behaviour is happening?

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="contextMenu" IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="False">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Background="AliceBlue">
                    <ListBox Name="ContextMenuList"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             SelectionChanged="ContextMenuListSelectionChanged" />

                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContextMenuListBinding}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ContextMenuListBinding,
                        Mode=OneWay}"

                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>


public void PositionContextMenu()
    {

        contextMenu.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(700, 250, 40, 30);
        contextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Absolute;
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

When i debug my code contextmenu.Isopen always shows its value as false.

The call to the function is made inside MouseLeftbuttonDown Event:-

```
 void MapMouseLeftButtonDownCommand(MouseEventArgs e)
    {

           var mycontextmenu = new MyContextMenu();

        mycontextmenu.PositionContextMenu();
    }
```

MyContextMenu is the Control which contain my popup.

Comment: Did you try setting StaysOpen to true ? Some kind of interaction may happen and close your Popup. If you need StaysOpen to be false, you can also try to play with FocusManager.IsFocusScope attached property.

Comment: I tried both. StaysOpen as well as FocusManager. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug code (e.g. raise a breakpoint) you're loosing focus from your popup. When a popup dosn't have the `StaysOpen` property set to true, it will close itself when it looses focus. The same will happen for instance if you switch to another window/application and then switch back to your form, you will see that the popup has closed.

The `IsOpen` is really false at that stage since the popup has (or is in the middle of) closing itself.

To see that everything works as it is supposed to, instead of a breakpoint add this line:
`Debug.Print(contextMenu.IsOpen.ToString());`

You will see that you still get a true, since you didn't use a breakpoint and didn't loose focus.

Comment: Debug.Print is returning false. Even without breakpoint no popup is showing. Any other way i can try ?

Comment: Where did you place the call to PositionContextMenu method?

Comment: I am calling it from MouseLeftButtonDown Event implementation.

Comment: Please add more relevant XAML and the code behind in your question

Comment: One more point to add I am doing all this on a Arcgis Map if that is of any help.

Comment: @Sunil - Did you check this simple popup control on a simple side-project? To try to pinpoint your problem? Also, still waiting for some more code...

Comment: Don't create a new MyContextMenu on every click. Create the MyContextMenu in the XAML of the window you want to use it in, give it an x:Name="myMenu", and on left click call myMenu.PositionContextMenu();

Comment: We can work out in numerous way.this is how the requirement is. I have to keep it as a separate usercontrol.  The question however is why am i not able to set its property to true. During debug as well when i try to change its value it doesn't work.I just made a sample example and  I can set its value to true. My popup is also opening.what makes this popup value as readonly ?

Comment: 1. You are creating a new usercontrol in the scope of a function 2. You leave the scope of that function 3. The usercontrol dies! ..... It has NOTHING to do specifically with a popup. It has nothing to do with if it's a usercontrol or not. If you want the usercontrol to bind to things in your view. You need to create it outside the scope of the function, give it a relevent datacontext and create bindings. All this can be done via codebehind or in XAML. But your original question is just the symptom, not the problem.

Comment: Hi Blaschshma ! I think it is a good practise to do the way you have told.  I tried it and it is working. Thanks !